# Bootstrap set radio button checked with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have radio buttons in my html code.
I want to change their state based on my input values via jquery

Here is My Html

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-offset-1">
 <div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rdo_pkdrop" value="0" id="rdo_pick">
     Pick-up Time
   </label>
 </div>
 <div class="radio">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="rdo_pkdrop" id="rdo_drop" value="1">
    Drop Time
   </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

An jQuery is

```
if(qs_trip_type == 0){
   $('#rdo_pick').prop('checked',true); 
}else{
   $('#rdo_pick').prop('checked',true); 
}
```

But This has no effect
I also tried with
  `$('#rdo_pick').prop('checked','checked');` and

```
$('#rdo_pick').attr('checked','true'); 
  $('#rdo_pick').addClass('checked');
```

Comment: Sorry It was Spelling Mistake.Its else

Comment: None of following answer is working with boostrap css

Comment: it has nothing to do with bootstarap css , there might be some problem with your js

Answer (score 14):

This is only way I could find. Although somewhat inelegant, it does work.

```
if(qs_trip_type == 0){
  $('#rdo_pick').click(); 
}else{
  $('#rdo_drop').click(); 
}
```

Comment: 'inelegant', indeed...... - however, it was the one that worked for me, too! :)

Answer (score 7):

The issue with bootstrap is that you set a checked radio button by adding the `active` class to the corresponding label of the input. It looks like this:

```
<label class="btn btn-default active">    <!-- Note the class 'active' here -->
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="value1" checked="checked"/>Value 1
</label>
<!-- ... -->
```

To check a radio button using jQuery you could first select the input field with a jQuery Selector and then add the class to the parent:

```
var $myRadioInput = $(...);
$myRadioInput.parent('.btn').addClass('active');
```

Don't forget to remove the class `active` on the formerly selected label with jQuery `removeClass('active')` to first unselect them.

I also like it to set the `checked` property on the input itself to have the proper state on it:

```
$myRadioInput.prop('checked', true);
```

Note that the `checked="checked"` attribute is only the inital state for the input to be the checked input when loading the page. It does NOT change with the jQuery `.prop()` method, as it is an attribute and is different to the actual `checked property`. This is well described in [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Though this is probably the way to do it. However, I find it kinda weird that in such a widespread GUI toolkit, one needs to do clunky fiddlery in order to obtain fundamental functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried，this code is ok for bootstrap  radio.

```
if(qs_trip_type == 0){
   $('#rdo_pick').prop('checked',true).click();
}else{ //not ekse
   $('#rdo_pick').prop('checked',true).click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a typo in your code replace `ekse` with `else`

```
   if(qs_trip_type == 0){
       $('#rdo_pick').prop('checked',true); 
    }else{
       $('#rdo_pick').prop('checked',true); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(qs_trip_type == 0){
   $('#rdo_pick').prop('checked',true); 
}else{ //not ekse
   $('#rdo_pick').prop('checked',true); 
}
```

Here's the jsfidlle http://jsfiddle.net/urLh9qnh/

Comment: Yes dear it is working with normal css.But not with bootstrap

Comment: @VijayTambade  didn't understand.Can you jsfiddle it??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(qs_trip_type == 0){
   $('#rdo_pick').prop('checked',true); 
}else{
   $('#rdo_drop').prop('checked',true); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
after setting the value of the radio, please add this code

```
$("input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']").iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one line solution:

```
$('#rdo_pick').iCheck('check');
```